# validating date in zendframework2

Tags: validation, zend-framework2

Hiho,
I would like to validate a date field from an zf2 
form. I set the 'format' option to get the format I need.
But at every time I validate it i get an error.
The validator looks like this:

```
            $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'user_data_birth',
            'required' => false,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                'name' => 'Date',
                'options' => array(
                    'format' => 'd.m.Y',
                    'locale' => 'de',
                    'messages' => array(
                        \Zend\Validator\Date::INVALID => 'Das scheint kein gÃ¼ltiges Datum zu sein.',
                        \Zend\Validator\Date::INVALID_DATE => 'Das scheint kein gÃ¼ltiges Datum zu sein. (Invalid Date)',
                        \Zend\Validator\Date::FALSEFORMAT => 'Das Datum ist nicht im richtigen Format.',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'name' => 'NotEmpty',
                    'options' => array(
                    'messages' => array(
                        \Zend\Validator\NotEmpty::IS_EMPTY => 'Bitte geben Sie das Datum an'
                        ),
                    ),
                )
            ),
        )));
```

But I get every time an error that the date is in the wrong format.

Comment: Could you provide the date which gives you problems?

Comment: The reported validation error is also required.

Comment: The date that gives the problem is the following: 09.06.1982 (same by 9.6.1982). Thats come from an form.

The validation error is: 

> The input does not appear to be a valid date

or after an reload one of my self defined errors. So it seems that it switch the error messages.

Answer (score 14):

You can solve the problem of, start date should be less than end date validation,  using the Callback function as below:

```
          $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name' => 'end_date',
                'required' => true,                 
                'filters' => array(
                        array('name' => 'StripTags'),
                        array('name' => 'StringTrim'),
                ),
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name' => 'Callback',
                        'options' => array(
                            'messages' => array(
                                    \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'The end date should be greater than start date',
                            ),
                            'callback' => function($value, $context = array()) {                                    
                                $startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $context['start_date']);
                                $endDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y', $value);
                                return $endDate >= $startDate;
                            },
                        ),
                    ),                          
                ),
        )));
```

Using the above code, I have solved my problem. I hope this helps.

Comment: Use anonymous function breaks the cache. I advice to use a class instead

Answer (score 1):

need to change validator which is in date element. If you pass format into the element you will be fine. You can take validator from element too.

```
$date = new Element\DateTime('test');
$date->setFormat('d.m.Y');
```

or

```
$validators = $date->getValidators()
// apply you changes
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with another format like the basic: 'Y-m-d' ?
What is the result?

Comment: I resolved it. I don't use the ValidatorFactory. instead I validate the date seperatly and this works fine.

Answer (score 0):

CallBack function is a very convenient way if we need to use this only in one form. Most times we will need to use this in more than one place. I did some research and wrote this custom validator. This validator compares two strings; I have added another trick to see if we need these strings to be different or same.

If we are changing the password; then the old password and the new password to be different at the same time we need the new password verification to be the same as the new password. This validator can be used be used for both cases just by changing the different parameter to be "true" or "false".

```
Form Fields
user_password
new_user_password
new_user_password_verify
```

create a new validator StringCompare.php in Application\src\Application\Validator

```
<?php

namespace Application\Validator;

class StringCompare extends \Zend\Validator\AbstractValidator {

    const SAME = 'same';
    const DIFFERENT = 'different';

    protected $messageTemplates = array(
        self::SAME => "Both the words are the same",
        self::DIFFERENT => "Both the words are different",
    );

    protected $messageVariables = array(
        'compareWith' => array( 'options' => 'compareWith' ),
        'different' => array( 'options' => 'different' ),
    );

    protected $options = array(
        'compareWith' => "",
        'different' => true,
        'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    );

    public function __construct( $options = array( ) ) {
        parent::__construct( $options );
    }

    public function getCompareWith( ) {
        return $this->options[ 'compareWith' ];
    }

    public function getDifferent( ) {
        return $this->options[ 'different' ];
    }

    public function isValid( $value, $context=array( ) ) {

        $compareWith = $this->getCompareWith( );
        $different = $this->getDifferent( );

        $returnValue =  $value == $context[$compareWith];
        if ( $different ) {
            $returnValue = !$returnValue;
       if ( !$returnValue ) {
          $this->error( self::SAME );
           }
        } else {
        if ( !$returnValue ) {
        $this->error( self::DIFFERENT );
        }
    }
        return $returnValue;


    }

}
```

Add the following to the Form filter

```
$this->add ( array (
    'name'  => 'new_user_password',
    'required' => true,
    'filters' => array (
        array ( 
            'name' => 'StringTrim',
        ),
    ),
    'validators' => array (
        array (
            'name' => 'StringLength',
            'options' => array (
                'min' => 8,
                'max' => 20,
            )
        ),
        array (
            'name' => 'Application\Validator\StringCompare',
            'options' => array (
                'compareWith' => 'user_password',
                'different' => true,
            ),
        ),
    )
) );
```

Perform the form validation in your controller and we are through.
If we use different = 'true' the validation routine ensures the two values are different, if we use 'false', then it ensures that the strings are the same.