# zend framework 2 - compare 2 inputs using validator?

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2, zend-form, zend-validate

I'm new to zend framework 2 and I have a question on comparing two inputs in the factory-backed form. My scenario is like following:

I want to compare two inputs, for example, `$startDate` and `$endDate`. I want to validate that `$startDate` is always less than `$endDate`. How I'm going to do this? For example:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
                'name'     => 'startDate',
                'required' => true,
                'validators' => array(
                    array(
                        'name'    => 'LessThan',
                        'options' => array(
                            'max'      => $endDate,
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            )));
```

FYI, I'm following the Album tutorial and the `$inputFilter` is created in the `classTable.php`.

Thanks

Comment: or is that other way to achieve this? Thanks...

Comment: You could use the Callback validator in a similar manner to this answer -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17529906/zf2-validation-how-can-i-validate-dependent-fields/17532467#17532467

Answer (score 4):

Thanks to Crisp! I solved it with something similar:

```
$inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name'     => 'startDate',
            'required' => true,
            'name'     => 'Callback',
                'options' => array(
                    'message' => array( 
                        Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'Invalid period is given.',
                    ),
                    'callback' => function($value, $context=array()) {
                        return $value < $context['endDate'];
                    },
                ),
            )));
```

Comment: The key 'name' is mentioned twice

Answer (score 0):

The above answer probably be correct, but there might be some syntax or Callback error might be occur. The reason is, We generally use Callback Validation function in Models InputFilters, Not in a forms definition section(as of Zend Framework version 2.2.1).

This call back script part should come inside Model - InputFilters, Please refer this link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19263037/2190889

As per this Url reference, date validation part works perfectly.