# Compare Two DateSelect Form Values

Tags: php, zend-framework2

I have two `Zend\Form\Element\Dateselect` elements in my form and I'm trying to validate that `dateEnd > dateBeg`.

These are the values in my form:

```
    $startDate = new DateSelect('dateBeg');
    $startDate->setLabel('Start Date');
    $startDate->setMinYear(2016);
    $startDate->setMaxYear(date("Y"));
    $startDate->setDayAttributes(array(
        'name' => 'dayBeg',
    ));
    $startDate->setMonthAttributes(array(
        'name' => 'monthBeg',
    ));
    $startDate->setYearAttributes(array(
        'name'=> 'yearBeg',
    ));
    $this->add($startDate);

    $endDate = new DateSelect('dateEnd');
    $endDate->setLabel('End Date');
    $endDate->setMinYear(2016);
    $endDate->setMaxYear(date("Y"));
    $endDate->setDayAttributes(array(
        'name' => 'dayEnd',
    ));
    $endDate->setMonthAttributes(array(
        'name' => 'monthEnd',
    ));
    $endDate->setYearAttributes(array(
        'name'=> 'yearEnd',
    ));
    $this->add($endDate);
```

I saw this solution for comparing two `Date` elements: [zend framework 2 - compare 2 inputs using validator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848591/zend-framework-2-compare-2-inputs-using-validator)

I tried to use this in my validation file, but the validation of `dateEnd` seems to only be affected by the 'required' filter and not my custom validator.

```
    $inputFilter->add($factory->createInput(array(
            'name' => 'dateEnd',
            'required' => false,
            'validators' => array(
                array(
                    'name' => 'Callback',
                    'options' => array(
                        'messages' => array(
                                \Zend\Validator\Callback::INVALID_VALUE => 'The end date should be greater than start date',
                        ),
                        'callback' => function($value, $context = array()) {                                     
                            $startDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $context['dateBeg']);
                            $endDate = \DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $value);
                            return $endDate > $startDate;
                        },
                    ),
                ),                          
            ),
        )));
```

I modified my form to use `Date` instead of `DateSelect` and this validation seems to work as intended, but I would prefer to use the `DateSelect` element. My guess is that there is something wrong with the `Callback` function / validator because I've used debug messages in there, but they don't get called. Is there a reason this validator isn't being called on my form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was not using the proper methods for calling the form in my `.phtml` file. I left out:

```
  $this->form->prepare();
  $this->form->setAttribute('action', $this->url('controller/action'));
  $this->form->setAttribute('method', 'post');
  $this->form->setAttribute('autocomplete', 'off');
```

So, the form rendered properly after. Otherwise you have day, month, year elements submitted in your form.